# Solving $y^{'} + \sqrt{1+{y^{'}}^2}=Ce^{x/k}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My memories about ODE are rather old. I would appreciate any help driving me to the solution of this equation:
$$y^{'} + \sqrt{1+{y^{'}}^2}=Ce^{x/k}$$

where $C$ and $k$ are constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you square the whole expression, you obtain
$$y'^2+1+y'^2+2y'\sqrt{1+y'^2}=C^2e^{2x/k}$$ and since $$\sqrt{1+y'^2}=Ce^{x/k}-y'$$ we have
$$2y'^2+1+2y'(Ce^{x/k}-y')=C^2e^{2x/k}$$ which reduces to
$$1+2Ce^{x/k}y'=C^2e^{2x/k}$$
or
$$y=C_0+\int \frac{C^2e^{2x/k}-1}{2Ce^{x/k}}$$

Comment: Wow, very subtle indeed...

Answer (score 2):

Consider $ (y'-C e^{x/k})^2=\sqrt{1+y'}^2$. That will simplify your expression.

Answer (score 2):

Parametrize $y'(x)=\sinh(u(x))$. Then
$$
Ce^{x/k}=y'(x)+\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}=\sinh(u(x))+\cosh(u(x))=e^{u(x)}
$$
Thus inserting backwards
$$
y'(x)=\sinh(u)=\frac12(e^{u(x)}-e^{-u(x)})=\frac12\left(Ce^{x/k}-\frac1{Ce^{x/k}}\right)
$$